# Getting empty value from Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

New to AWS and working on Lambda with Node.JS

I have the following code works on my local, but once I uploaded to Lambda (via CLI with successful status) .. however I realized it complaint about `index.hanlder` issue. Hence after Googling, I updated my code to the 2nd version, it runs fine with Status 200 but return me a NULL.

I've tested the local code and it returns my data from DynamoDB. What seems to be the mistake here?

To provide extra information:

- My .zip contains the following (index.js, node_modules, package-lock.json, package.json)

**Local Code**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();
const awsSDK = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new awsSDK.DynamoDB({region:'maskedData', apiVersion:'maskedData'});

router.get('/get', (req,res) => {
const params = {
        TableName: "maskedData"
    };
    dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            // callback(err);
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            // callback(null, data);
            res.send(data);
        }
    })

})

module.exports = router;
```

**2nd Version**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();
const awsSDK = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new awsSDK.DynamoDB({region:'maskedData', apiVersion:'maskedData'});

exports.handler = router.get('/get', (req,res) => {
// router.get('/get', (req,res) => {
const params = {
        TableName: "maskedData"
    };
    dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            // callback(err);
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            // callback(null, data);
            res.send(data);
        }
    })

})

// module.exports = router
// exports.handler = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be used as lambda you need to have handler function which have event, context and callback parameter (optional). Something like this

```
const express = require("express");
const awsSDK = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamodb = new awsSDK.DynamoDB({"region": "maskedData", "apiVersion": "maskedData"});

exports.handler = async event => {
  const params = {
    "TableName": "maskedData"
  };
  const data = await dynamodb.scan(params).promise();
  return data;
};
```

aws sdk supports promise version so you can use that instead of callback based.

Comment: I do aware there is this Event, Context, Callback. In fact, I practice on Lambda Editor before moving to code on local. However, if I were to do this on my local, how am I suppose to handle the express and express.router() ??

Comment: what is your use case for lambda? Are you trying to use express on lambda?

Comment: Yes, will be using Express, Body-Parser and etc on Lambda.

Comment: how are you planning to use the express api from lambda? I don't think thay is the right way to go about it. How will you access the routes? and since lambda is short lived, the express app will go away

Comment: Or did I understand the concept incorrectly? Im working on a mockserver on my local. Hence I have app.js to connect to different files and functions.. that's is the reason why I need to have Express, Router(), Body-Parser in place for App.js and other files and functions.

Comment: I don't think lambda is the for that as as soon as your work is done it will kill the server you created and the end point you expose wouldn't be accessible from outside. Lambda is for doing small work which can be completed in itself. If you need to use lambda as a backend and serverless api, then you need to use AWS API Gateway and lambda both.

Comment: I think you just woke me up.. lambda is stateless and meant to be performed quick tasks. Thank you for pointing out and quick answer!

Comment: @AshishModi I believe there is a gap in your conception of use cases for Lambda. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express is the wrapper for running express apps inside Lambda but is primarily intended for adapting existing applications since express isn't actually needed for Lambda hosted apps.  The web server in front of this setup is Amazon API Gateway or Application Load Balancer, either of which invokes the Lambda function for each request.  The express server doesn't remain running, as it would in a non-serverless environment.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I am aware of this repo you just talked about. If you read some of my previous comments, it does say about this.